# How do you get and set a 1-D array with column indexes of a 2-D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have a matrix:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

and I want get or set over the values 1, 5, and 6, how would I do that.

For example I thought doing

```py
# getting
b = a[:, np.array([1,2,0])]
# want b = [1,5,6]

# setting
a[:, np.array([1,2,0])] = np.array([9, 10, 11])
# want:
# a = array([[0, 9, 2],
#            [3, 4, 10],
#            [11, 7, 8]])
```

would do it, but that is not the case. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a small tweak makes this work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

# getting
b = a[range(a.shape[0]), np.array([1,2,0])]

# setting
a[range(a.shape[0]), np.array([1,2,0])] = np.array([9, 10, 11])
```

The reason why your code didn't work as expected is because you were indexing the x-axis with slices instead of indices. Slices mean take all rows, but specifying the index directly will get you the row you want for each index value.